# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when splitting bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image

Can  someone tell me why I am getting this error when splitting a bitmap.
Code:

```
 public static List<Bitmap> ScambleImage(Bitmap image, int rows, int cols){
    List<Bitmap> scambledImage =  new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    int chunkWidth = image.getWidth(); //cols
    int chunkHeight = image.getHeight(); //rows
    int finalSize = chunkWidth/rows;

    Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, chunkWidth, chunkHeight, true);
    int yCoord = 0;//The y coordinate of the first pixel in source
    for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
        int xCoord = 0;//The x coordinate of the first pixel in source
        for(int y = 0; y < cols; y++){
            scambledImage.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, xCoord, yCoord, finalSize, finalSize));
            xCoord = finalSize + xCoord;
        }
        yCoord = finalSize + yCoord;//The y coordinate of the first pixel in source
    }

    return scambledImage;
}
```

rows = 6, and cols = 6;
image size = 648 x 484

this is the exception but don't know how to go about fixing:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()
```

[Image I'm splitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlN4b.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to grab sections of the original bitmap that don't exist.

Put a breakpoint at the line:

```
scambledImage.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapScaled, xCoord, yCoord, finalSize,  finalSize));
```

And you'll see it fails sometime *after* the first array iteration because each time your offsetting the start point of which "slice" of the bigmap you are grabbing by xCoord/yCoord.

My hunch says your calculation for finalSize is wrong, but I can only speculate since we don't know exactly what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for the response, I'm trying to split the image into a 6 x 6 grid.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and changes a little bit and it works for me.

```
private ArrayList<Bitmap> splitImage(Bitmap bitmap, int rows, int cols){
    int chunks = rows*cols;
    int chunkHeight,chunkWidth;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> splittedImages = null;
    splittedImages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunks);
    chunkHeight = bitmap.getHeight()/rows;
    chunkWidth = bitmap.getWidth()/cols;
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
    int yCoord = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<rows; x++){
        int xCoord = 0;
        for(int y=0; y<cols; y++){
            splittedImages.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
            xCoord += chunkWidth;
        }
        yCoord += chunkHeight;
    }
    return splittedImages;
}
```